# Update a large mysql table with data from another table

Tags: mysql, join, sql-update

I have two tables 'Cast' and 'Roles'. Table 'Cast' fields are Id, castName, castID, roleId. Fields of table 'Roles' are Id, castId, role_Id

I want to update role_Id in table 'Roles' where it is null in this table and is equal to '1' in table 'Cast'.

This is what I wrote:

```
UPDATE Roles
INNER JOIN Cast on (Cast.castID = Roles.castId)
SET Roles.role_Id = '2'
WHERE Roles.role_Id IS NULL AND Cast.roleId = '1';
```

Could someone help me to understand what is the problem with this query and how can I update the table 'Roles'?

Comment: Your where condition satisfied condition according to your table data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I puted `Cast.roleId = '1'` condition at on clause

```
UPDATE Roles
INNER JOIN Cast on 
Cast.castID = Roles.castId  AND Cast.roleId = '1'
SET Roles.role_Id = '2'
WHERE Roles.role_Id IS NULL;
```

Comment: It didn't have a different result with my query :( (Actually I am not sure if my query was wrong because when I ran it, it worked but my doubt is because it only affected about 5000 rows while I expected more)

Comment: So, Before update query you have to write `Select` query for confirmation If return expected records then you can apply update query

Comment: select query for your answer returned an empty set

Comment: select query for your question returned what?

Comment: maybe I wrote in a wrong way: this is what I wrote: SELECT * FROM Roles INNER JOIN Cast on Cast.castID = Roles.castId AND Cast.roleId = '1' WHERE Roles.role_Id IS NULL;

Comment: select query for your asked question returned what data. Are you sure is it right?

Comment: my stupid mistake : I tried the update for copy of the table but I tested select for the original table, and my mistake was that in original table I had '0' instead of null!

Comment: yes, It worked for both queries, mine and also your query. and problem about upating only 5000 rows was that I was updating on a copy table, tnx anyway for your help :)